# Solving inequalities and drawing graph

Tags: inequality

I have the question " Find the set of values of X for which X^2 - 6X + 5 > 0"

I have solved this and got X = 1 or 5.

My question is when drawing the graph is 5 the y-intercept ?so does the curve cut through the y-axis at the point 5 or is 5 not the y intercept and if so where does should the curve cut the y - axis or does it not cut through the y - axis at all ?

[image: i got this for the answer]

But the solutions say the answer should be :

[image]

Comment: You've found where $X^2-6X+5$ is equal to zero, not where it's greater than zero.

Comment: Now that you have the zeros write your expression as $f(x) = (x-1)(x-5)$ and looks a the signs of each individual factor

Comment: Could you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too sure how the $y$-intercept helps with answering the question, but never the less, it *is* part of your problem.

> **Question 1:** When drawing the graph, is $5$ the $y$-intercept? So does the curve cut through the $y$-axis at the point $5$, or is $5$ not the $y$-intercept?

Yes, the parabola intercepts the $y$-axis. An easy way to find it is to set $x=0$, and see what's left.

(**Note:** You can just instead, look at the $c$ term in $ax^2+bx+c$. See if you can show it!)

---

> **Question 2:** Find the set of $x$ values such at $x^2-6x+5>0$

Graphing the polynomial, you will see that the values for which $y>0$ is when we have $(-\infty, 1]\cup [5,+\infty)$

Answer (score 1):

it is equivalent to $$(x-1)(x-5)>0$$ thus we get $$x<1$$ or $$x>5$$

Comment: I'm confused as to where the curve should cross the y-axis because sometimes it crosses through and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: you have to solve the inequality only for $x$

Comment: Could you please explain further?

Comment: Because I understand where the X points for the curve should be which is obviously 1 and 5 but I don't understand why sometimes the curve crosses through the y axis and sometimes the curve is just the two X points with no interference of the y - axis

Answer (score 1):

Look at the graph.It helps you understand the answer very easily.

When you plot $x^2-6x+5$ on the graph what you really mean is $y=x^2-6x+5$.Plugging in a particular value of $x$ gives you a corresponding value of $y$.

This type of thing is called a *function*.Its like an input output machine.

You need to find the set of all $x$ such that $x^2-6x+5>0$.So, this is equivalent to find all $x$ such that $y>0$.On the graph,the vertical axis is taken as $y-axis$ where the values of $y$ are shown for corresponding values of $x$.

Looking at the graph, we find between $1$ and $5$ the value of $y$ is below the origin,so $y$ is negative.And at $1$ and $5$,$y=0$.So,$y$ is clearly positive for all $x$ values which do not range from $1$ to $5$.

So,all real values of $x$ which do not range from $1$ to $5$ satisfies the equation.

Mathematically this can be written as $x<1$ and $x>5$.(Why? and How?)